# Orange SMS Gateway APi 1.1 is not working with php

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, orange-api

I purchased a number of messages , and followed all the steps
including 
1. access token 
2. client id and secret id

but the sms never reach the mobile number

iam using this code based on the api documentation

```
<?php
 require 'Path to Osms ';

 use \Osms\Osms;

 $config = array(
   'token' => 'my token'
  );

 $osms = new Osms($config);

 $senderAddress = "tel:+200000";
$receiverAddress = "tel:+20 my number";
 $message = "Hello World!";
 $senderName = "Optimus Prime";

  $osms->sendSms($senderAddress, $receiverAddress, $message, 
     $senderName);
```

what happens is that the number of messages at the website keeps decreasing , but the sms never arrives the mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this library](https://github.com/informagenie/orange-sms) instead of what you've used !

More explications are [here](https://informagenie.com/3141/envoyer-sms-orange-sms-api/)